# Given the base and angles of an isosceles triangle, how to find length of the two sides?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

I can't seem to find a textbook solution to this. It is always assumed that the length of the sides is know.

[image: Isosceles triangle]

[Isolceles triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdIzF.gif)

So the base $a$ is known. The bottom angles where $\alpha$ and the two sides $b$ touch, are known.

What is $h$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

solution sketch:

Note that $h$ divides the triangle into **two right triangles** (h is the perpendicular bisector (altitude) from the base to the opposite vertex); the angles line $h$ forms with $a$ are **right angles**. This gives you two right triangles, and you only need one of them to compute the values you need.

Call the two known (marked) angles $\theta$ (they are equal).

If you know the length of the side $b$: $\sin\theta = \dfrac{h}{b} \implies h = b\sin\theta$

If $a$ is known, $\tan\theta = \dfrac{h}{a/2} \implies h = \dfrac{a}{2}\tan \theta$.

---

Now, using the pythorean theorem to relate your sides, we know that

$$h^2+\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2\,=\;b^2\tag{pythogorean theorem}$$

If the length of $b$ is unknown, using the [**pythagorean theorem**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem), then knowing $a/2$ and $h$ will allow you to solve for $b$.

Knowing $\,b\,$ and $\,h\,$ will allow you to solve for $\,\dfrac{a}{2}\,$ by the pythagorean theorem Then double the value of $a/2$ to get $a$.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work. Likewise Inquisitive's answer. It's part of larger problem and i didn't get the results i expected, but that was a fault on my part. Your answer is correct.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

I have explained it graphically below.

[image: Height]

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate h

1) using a and b

(a/2) * (a/2) + h * h = b * b

2) using sine law or cosine law http://www.transtutors.com/math-homework-help/laws-of-triangle/

h/ sinα = b / sin 90

Answer (score 1):

from one of the following equations
$$h^2+\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2=b^2$$
$$\sin\alpha=\frac{h}{b}$$
$$\cos\alpha=\frac{h/2}{b}=\frac{h}{2b}$$
$$\tan\alpha=\frac{h}{a/2}=\frac{2h}{a}$$
if you know two elements you can find the missing one